Proof of uniqueness of power series representation of function
My question relates to the theorem and proof given in Erwin Kreyszig's Advanced engineering mathematics:

Theorem 1 is as follows:

My question is as follows: In the proof of Theorem 2, what is the justification for concluding $a_{m+1}$ = $b_{m+1}$, given that $a_{m+1}$ = $b_{m+1}$ only holds when z = 0 and the second equation has not been shown to be equivalent to the first at z = 0?

Lets review all the steps.
Base case: n=0
By hypothesis:
$$a_{0}+a_1z+a_2z^2+..=b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+... \quad |z|>0 $$
Then, taking the limit as $z \to 0$.
$$a_0 = b_0$$
Inductive step. Suppose this is valir for $n\leq m$:
$$ a_0 = b_0,\; b_1=b_1, \; a_3 = b_3, ...., a_m = b_m$$
Third step. We have to prove this for $n=m+1$
By hypothesis:
$$a_{0}+a_1z+a_2z^2+..=b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+... \quad |z|>0 $$
Then
$$(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+...+a_mz^m)+a_{m+1}z^{m+1}+.. = (b_0+a_1z+b_2z^2+...+b_mz^m)+b_{m+1}b^{m+1}+..$$
From the inductive step:
$$a_{m+1}z^{m+1}+a_{m+2}z^{m+2}+a_{m+3}z^{m+3}+.. = +b_{m+1}z^{m+1}+b_{m+2}z^{m+2}+b_{m+3}z^{m+3}+..$$
Given that $z\neq 0 $ we can divide both sides by $z^{m+1}$
$$a_{m+1}+a_{m+2}z+a_{m+3}z^{2}+.. = b_{m+1}+b_{m+2}z+b_{m+3}z^{2}+..$$
Taking the limit as $z\to 0$:
$$ a_{m+1} = b_{m+1}$$
Hence this is valid $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$

Thank you. But what is the motivation/justification for taking | z | > 0 in the hypothesis?

In step three you have to divide both sides by $z^{m+1}$, this is not possible if $z=0$. However, you still can calculate the limit as $z \to 0$. Perhaps you may ask: what happen with Taylor series is convergent and defined at $z=0$? In that particular case you always  have one term: $a_0$, there is no need for induction.

Given that we are looking at limits as z -> 0, but excluding z = 0 from our considerations, is the is the fact that the sums of the series are continuous at 0 relevant?

Yes it is relevant for taking the limit

Thank you. Could you perhaps explain why?

@DL1 Yes, suppose that the function is not continuous but the limit exists at $z=0$. For example a removable discontinuity. Then taking the limit as $z \to 0$ the limit exists but is not equal to $a_{0}$ or $b_{0}$ but instead $ a_{0}+ \underbrace{\lim_{z\to 0} (a_{1}z+a_2z^2+....)}{\neq 0} = b{0}+\underbrace{\lim_{z \to 0} (b_1z + b_2z^2+...)}{\neq 0} $. So, you cannot conclude that $a{0} = b_{0}$ and the base case fails.

But do we not have a similar problem for the second and subsequent steps anyway? We know that the two series of the nth step are each continuous at z = 0 and hence that $a_{n-1} = b_{n-1}$ for the series of the nth step, but we don't know that this equality holds at z = 0 for the series of the n-1th step, since we don't know that the series of the nth and n-1th steps are equivalent at z = 0.

@DL1 You raise a good subtle point. Note however that the new power series that occur in the later stages  can be confirmed to converge at some nonzero point chosen in the original disk of convergence, and then by the Continuity Theorem 1, they too must be continuous at z=0.

It would be helpful to post also the details of the proof of Theorem 1.  (If it proves that the power series is uniformly continuous on the disk  minus origin,  one can invoke a standard theorem to prove that the power series automatically extends as a continuous function across the origin.) A whole new level of subtlety!

The proof of Theorem 1 can be found on page 686 here: https://www.bau.edu.jo/UserPortal/UserProfile/PostsAttach/59003_3812_1.pdf
It is not prooved that the power series are continuous on the disc minus origin. Nevertheless, the problem that the series of the different steps have not been shown to be equivalent at the origin remains.

The left and right power series both converge at some nonzero point, hence ( as the book  discusses earlier )they both converge on a disk of some radius $R>0$ . By Theorem 1 these two convergent series   are continuous at the origin. But they  are two descriptions of the same function at all nonzero $z$. So their limits are the same.

@DL1 Yes, we do have a similar problem for the inductive step and the last step. But we do know this equality hold at $=0$. The rationale to exclude $=0$ is to divide by $z^{m+1}$ when $z\neq 0$. Theorem 1 is standard in complex analysis: if the coefficients are equal when $ 0<|z|$ they must be equal at $z\to 0$
and then due to the continuity of the series this means that the coefficients are also equal at $z=0$.
